# How to launch terminal.app from elisp

Tags: osx, shell, term

I've been using [shell-pop](http://github.com/kyagi/shell-pop-el) recently, and it's nice how I can pop to default-directory in term immediately. For the times I'd rather use a dedicated terminal, is it possible to create an equivalent for OSX's Terminal.app?

What I want is to call one function in emacs and launch Terminal.app cd'd automatically to default-directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```lisp
(defun my-applescript-fn ()
"Open the Terminal.app, wait a second, and CD to the Emacs default-directory
of current buffer."
(interactive)
(do-applescript
  (format
    "tell application \"Terminal\"
    activate
    delay 1
    try
    do script with command \"cd %s\" in window 1
    on error
    beep
    end try
    end tell" default-directory)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know if this would be considered off topic, but what is the proper applescript to account for the case of Terminal already running, but with no windows?

Comment: It is the `in window 1` that prevents a new window from launching.  If you remove that, then a new window is created.  I'd need to Google how to put in an `if/then` to test if a window exists . . . :)  I've only played around with a few applescripts and am still fairly unfamiliar with the language.

Answer (score 0):

The applescript version above didn't seem to work for me--this version is also potentially faster since it requires no `delay`:

```
(defun brds/open-Terminal-here ()
    (interactive)
    (shell-command
     (concat "open -a Terminal "
             (shell-quote-argument (expand-file-name
                                    default-directory))) nil nil))
```